# A permanent react native FAB button doesn't work on Android, but works on iOS?

Tags: android, react-native, floating-action-button

So I made a custom FAB (floating action button), that can be move around the screen, so it doesn't get in the way. I need the FAB to be permanent, as a quick navigation button. It's working just as expected on iOS, but not on android.

I basically put the fab component to App.tsx like so

```js
  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={colorScheme == 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
      <KeyboardAvoiderProvider>
        <SafeAreaProvider>
          {Navigation()}
          <Fab />
          <NotificationController />
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      </KeyboardAvoiderProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

But if I move the FAB component into a screen, say the home screen, it works. How do I make it so the fab is available on every screen?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. This is the link that lead me to the solution https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/1478

Basically I need to move `<GestureHandlerRootView>` out of the Fab component into App.tsx, like so:

```js
  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={colorScheme == 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
      <KeyboardAvoiderProvider>
        <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <SafeAreaProvider>
            {Navigation()}
            <Fab />
            <NotificationController />
          </SafeAreaProvider>
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
      </KeyboardAvoiderProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

Oddly it was never an issue on iOS